# Save text box including symbol for repeated use

Tags: ms-word, latex

Is it possible to save a text box with a symbol next to it (or inside of it if the first option does not work) for repeated quick use?

It does not necessarily have to be a text box, normal text formated to have a border works too. The important thing is that the format stays the same and that the symbol is also there.

example: [image: example]

If that is not possible in MS Word - is it possible in LaTeX?

Thank you.

I tried using a text box and setting it as "standard text box" and also tried to use a style template. The latter worked to keep the style the same but in both tries I was not able to make the symbol appear.

Comment: Such boxes are very easy in latex, e.g. the https://www.ctan.org/pkg/awesomebox or https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bclogo packages have such boxes out of the box (pun intended) and for a quick reuse one could create a custom macro for store them in a `\savebox` (depending on the use case)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thank you! I will try it in LaTeX but before I will wait if someone knows how to do it in MS word as this is (at least for me) easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now have found an possible solution: make a text box, format it and group it with the symbol. Select the group and then press `Alt + F3` and save it as you wish (i saved it in an own category in text boxes). Then for repeated use just go to `insert -> text box -> what you saved it as`.